# Hide parent records in primeng tree-table filtering

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-treetable

[image]I have applied a filter to my tree-table, i only want to **show the rows with filtered data and hide the parent records**. The code is available at https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treetablefilter-demo - using a variant of this. Added a picture- i don't want the parent record - in my case, the level of indentation is more but the challenge is similar

Comment: Please provide the source code, current results and expected result so we can help.
please read this official guide [how-to-ask-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @SaadAbbasi can you pls help here, have added code and picture as well